# Redux state loading, but react not rending

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

So I'm fetching data from the server side. State is loading in redux, but react isn't rendering the array that's in state.

Here's my components from react:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { IonContent, IonButton, IonButtons, IonToolbar, IonTitle, IonHeader,  IonList } from "@ionic/react";
import { IInviteModal, IInviteReduxProps } from "../types/interfaces";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {getInvites} from '../flux/actions/eventActions';
import InviteListItem from "./InviteListItem";

const InviteModal = ({ getInvites, invite, onDismissModal}: IInviteModal) => {
  
// const [invites, setInvites] = useState();

  useEffect(() => { 
    getInvites(); 
  }, [getInvites]);

  // const { invites } = invite;
  const {invites}  = {...invite}

  const handleOnSubmit = (e: any) => {
      e.preventDefault();
 };
    
  return (
        <IonContent>
          <form onSubmit={handleOnSubmit}>
              <IonHeader>
              <IonToolbar>
                <IonButtons slot="start">
                    <IonButton 
                    onClick={onDismissModal}
                    >
                        Back
                    </IonButton>
                </IonButtons>
              <IonTitle>
                <div className="ion-text-center">
                Event Invites
                </div>
              </IonTitle>
            </IonToolbar>
            </IonHeader>
            <IonList>
                {
                invites ? 
                invites.map(invite => <InviteListItem 
                invite={invite}
                key={invite._id}
                />
                )
                : "Loading..."
              }
            </IonList>
          </form>
          </IonContent>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state: IInviteReduxProps) => ({
  invite: state.invite
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getInvites })(InviteModal);

import React from 'react';
import {  IonItem, IonLabel, IonButton, IonGrid, IonRow, IonCol } from '@ionic/react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {setCurrentI} from '../flux/actions/eventActions';
import { IInviteListItem } from '../types/interfaces';
import {format} from "date-fns";
 
const InviteListItem = ({ invite, setCurrentI }: IInviteListItem) => {

  const setCurrentInvite = (invite: any) => {setCurrentI(invite)};

  return (
          <div>          
              <IonItem
              onClick={() => setCurrentInvite(invite)}
              >
                <IonLabel>
                <h2>{invite.title}</h2>
                <p>{invite.location}</p>
                <br />
                <p>{format(new Date(invite.dateStart), "MMM d', 'h:mm aaa")}&mdash;&nbsp;
                  {format(new Date(invite.dateEnd), "MMM d', 'h:mm aaa")}</p>
                  {/* <br /> */}
                  <div className="ion-text-center">
                <IonGrid>
                  <IonRow>
                    <IonCol>
                      <IonButton size="small" fill="clear">
                      Accept
                      </IonButton>
                    </IonCol>
                    <IonCol>
                      <IonButton size="small" fill="clear">
                      _
                      </IonButton>
                    </IonCol>
                    <IonCol>
                      <IonButton size="small" fill="clear">
                      Decline
                      </IonButton>
                    </IonCol>
                  </IonRow>
                </IonGrid>
                </div>
                </IonLabel>
              </IonItem>
        </div>      
  );
};

export default connect(null, {setCurrentI})(InviteListItem);
```

Here's the reducer:

```
import {GET_EVENTS, GET_EVENT, ADD_EVENT, DELETE_EVENT, EVENTS_LOADING, UPDATE_EVENT, SET_CURRENT, CLEAR_CURRENT, LOG_ARRIVAL, EVENT_ERROR, GET_INVITES} from '../actions/types';
import {IAction, IEvent, IInvite} from '../../types/interfaces';

const initialState = {
    events: [],
    invites: [],
    current: [],
    loading: false
};

interface IState {
    events: IEvent[];
    invites: IInvite[];
  }
  
export default function(state: IState=initialState, action: IAction){
    switch(action.type){
        case GET_EVENTS:
            return{
                ...state,
                events: action.payload,
                loading: false
            };
        case GET_INVITES:
            return{
                ...state,
                invites: action.payload,
                loading: false
            };
}
```

[Page not mapping array, state is loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xxq1U.png)
[Diff redux output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7wBk.png)

The page is only showing "Loading..."

What's weird is that I'm using exactly the same structure to get other data and the array maps without issue.

Any ideas on how to get array to render?

Here's the code that is working:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { IonContent, IonLabel, IonList } from '@ionic/react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {getEvents} from '../flux/actions/eventActions';
import { IEventReduxProps, ICalendar } from '../types/interfaces';
import EventListItem from './EventListItem';


const Calendar = ({ getEvents, event }: ICalendar) => {

  useEffect(() => { 
    getEvents(); 
  }, [getEvents]);
 
  const { events } = event;

  return (
    <IonContent>
      <IonList>
          {events.map(event => <EventListItem 
          event={event} 
          key={event._id}/>
          )
          }
      </IonList>
    </IonContent>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state: IEventReduxProps) => ({
  event: state.event
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getEvents })(Calendar);

import React from 'react';
import {  IonItem, IonIcon, IonLabel, IonButton } from '@ionic/react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {deleteEvent, setCurrent} from '../flux/actions/eventActions';
import { IEventListItem } from '../types/interfaces';
import { closeCircle } from 'ionicons/icons';
import {format} from "date-fns";

const EventListItem = ({ event, deleteEvent, setCurrent }: IEventListItem) => {

  const handleDelete = (_id: string) => {deleteEvent(_id);};
  const setCurrentEvent = (event: any) => {setCurrent(event);};

  return (
          <div>          
              <IonItem  
              onClick={() => setCurrentEvent(event)}
              // routerLink={`/event/${event._id}`}          
              >
                <IonLabel>
                <h2>{event.title}</h2>
                <p>{event.location}</p>
                <p>{format(new Date(event.dateStart), "MMM d', 'h:mm aaa")}&mdash;&nbsp;
                  {format(new Date(event.dateEnd), "MMM d', 'h:mm aaa")}</p>
                  {/* MAP the ATTENDEES */}
                  {event.attendees.map((attendee, _id)=> (
                  <p key={attendee._id} >
                    {attendee.name}
                    {/* {attendee.email} */}
                  </p>
                  )
                  )}
                </IonLabel>
                <IonButton
                routerLink={`/event/log/${event._id}`}
                color="success"
                fill="clear"
                >Log</IonButton>
                
                <IonButton
                routerLink={`/event/${event._id}`}
                fill="clear"
                >Edit</IonButton>
                <IonIcon 
                    icon={closeCircle} 
                    slot="end"
                    className="remove-btn"
                    color="danger"
                    onClick={() => handleDelete(event._id)}
                    />
              </IonItem>
        </div>      
  );
};



export default connect(null, { deleteEvent, setCurrent })(EventListItem);
```

Comment: Could you provide reducer for `getInvites` and screenshot with redux dev tools (tab diff)?

Comment: is `getInvites` a function that is already bound to your redux store? try replacing `connect(mapStateToProps, { getInvites })(InviteModal);` with `connect(mapStateToProps, dispatch => bindActionCreators({ getInvites }))(InviteModal);`

Comment: @KirillSkomarovskiy Done, I also added the code that is working without issue.

Comment: @JacobSmit getting an error when trying your solution for getInvites: "An argument for 'dispatch' was not provided"

Comment: sorry, I was away for a week. `bindActionCreators({ getInvites })` should include dispatch as the second parameter `bindActionCreators({ getInvites }, dispatch)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have data in `redux store` then you have to add `useSelector()` from `react-redux`.

On that way you will notify component when new `props` come in application and that will cause component to `re-render` with new data.

And also problem is cause you are using `import { connect } from "react-redux";` and `hooks` together.

You have to decide do you want to use `redux` with `hooks` or `class`.

If you want to use it with hooks then you need: `useSelector`, `useActions` .

If you want to use it with class components then you need from redux: `mapStateToProps`, `mapDispatchToProps`, `connect`.

Shortly: You are mixing two different approaches.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you bumped some problem with `connect`. HOC [connect](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#connect) has 4 arguments. A special [options](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#options-object)
I have not identified your problem. Could you try two components bellow?

If this code does not help - I think your problem in reducer, action, middleware.

#### InviteModal.tsx

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { IonContent, IonButton, IonButtons, IonToolbar, IonTitle, IonHeader,  IonList } from '@ionic/react';

import { getInvites } from '../flux/actions/eventActions';

import { IInviteModal, IInviteReduxProps } from '../types/interfaces';
import InviteListItem from './InviteListItem';
/* TODO: make correct IInviteModal */
const InviteModal: React.FC<IInviteModal> = ({ onDismissModal }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { invites } = useSelector(({ invite }: IInviteReduxProps) => invite);

  React.useEffect(() => { 
    dispatch(getInvites());
  }, [dispatch]);

  const handleOnSubmit = React.useCallback((e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  }, []);
    
  return (
    <IonContent>
      <form onSubmit={handleOnSubmit}>
        <IonHeader>
          <IonToolbar>
            <IonButtons slot="start">
              <IonButton onClick={onDismissModal}>
                Back
              </IonButton>
            </IonButtons>
            
            <IonTitle>
              <div className="ion-text-center">
                Event Invites
              </div>
            </IonTitle>
          </IonToolbar>
        </IonHeader>

        <IonList>
          {
          invites
            ? invites.map(invite => <InviteListItem invite={invite} key={invite._id} />)
            : "Loading..."
          }
        </IonList>
      </form>
    </IonContent>
  );
};

export default InviteModal;
```

#### InviteListItem.tsx

```js
import React from 'react';
import {  IonItem, IonLabel, IonButton, IonGrid, IonRow, IonCol } from '@ionic/react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { format } from 'date-fns';

import { setCurrentI } from '../flux/actions/eventActions';

import { IInviteListItem } from '../types/interfaces';

const formatData = (data: string) => format(new Date(data), "MMM d', 'h:mm aaa");
/* TODO: make correct IInviteListItem */
const InviteListItem: React.FC<IInviteListItem> = ({ invite }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const setCurrentInvite = React.useCallback(() => {
    dispatch(setCurrentI(invite));
  }, [invite, dispatch]);

  return (
    <IonItem onClick={setCurrentInvite}>
      <IonLabel>
        <h2>{invite.title}</h2>
        
        <p>{invite.location}</p>
        
        <br />
        
        <p>
          {formatData(invite.dateStart)}
          &mdash;&nbsp;
          {formatData(invite.dateEnd)}
        </p>

        <div className="ion-text-center">
          <IonGrid>
            <IonRow>
              <IonCol>
                <IonButton size="small" fill="clear">
                  Accept
                </IonButton>
              </IonCol>

              <IonCol>
                <IonButton size="small" fill="clear">
                  _
                </IonButton>
              </IonCol>
              
              <IonCol>
                <IonButton size="small" fill="clear">
                  Decline
                </IonButton>
              </IonCol>
            </IonRow>
          </IonGrid>
        </div>
      </IonLabel>
    </IonItem>
  );
};

export default InviteListItem;
```

Comment: This is throwing all kinds of errors on my main page where all of this is rendering.

Comment: @morethan1 could you provide screen or text?

Comment: You were correct, this had to do with my reducers. I created separate reducers and actions for Invites and all is working properly now. Thanks